# Многопоточный парсер веб страниц на Python

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Есть порядка 80000 ссылок записаных в базу, с товаром.Я в цикле перехожу по каждой ссылки и считываю полученные данные и выбираю, характеристики нужные мне по товару. На это уходит очень много времени.

Как мне реализовать простую многопоточную схему по извлечению информации? Искал в интернете и мало чего нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте Pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_page(link):
    ....

links = ("link1", "link2".....)
pool = Pool()
pool.map(get_page, links)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Можно использовать потоки вместо процессов для IO задач. Вместо `pool.close()`, лучше `with ThreadPool() as pool:` на случай  выброса исключения. `pool.join()` здесь не нужен. Для `80_000` ссылок, [стоит `imap_unordered()` вызывать и ошибки записывать.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986480/4279). Может быть удобней `concurrent.futures` использовать, если повторно неудавшиеся ссылки в пул отсылать (submit(), as_completed()).

Comment: т.е. вместо multiprocessing надо multiprocessing.dummy.

Comment: Верно. Или явно ThreadPool (это одно и то же)